# iter over dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate over a Dataframe like this:

```
for i in y.itertuples(): print i
```

result:

```
(datetime.date(2012, 9, 10), 63.930000305175781, 64.589996337890625, 63.880001068115234, 64.099998474121094, 507700.0, 64.099998474121094)
(datetime.date(2012, 9, 11), 63.490001678466797, 63.790000915527344, 62.509998321533203, 63.759998321533203, 896600.0, 63.759998321533203)
```

How can I create a new Dataframe of each iterated tuple with indexing the date object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records([i], index=0)
```